# SQL: how to join tables with same meaning but different column name?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have table student, and table advisor.
student contains ID and name:

```
+----+------+
| ID | name | 
+----+------+
```

advisor contains s_id and i_id:

```
+------+------+
| s_id | i_id | 
+------+------+
```

how to join with result like this:

```
+----+------+------+
| ID | name | i_id | 
+----+------+------+
```

I've tried

```
select *
from student join advisor on student.ID=advisor.s_id
```

But it returns

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | name | i_id | s_id |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you at least tried to write a query yet?  Can you include that in your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've included one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your existing query by including in the select list only the columns you actually want to see:

```sql
SELECT s.ID, s.name, a.i_id
FROM student s
INNER JOIN advisor a
    on s.ID = a.s_id;
```

In case a given student might actually have no advisors, you could use a left join here to report `NA` for that student:

```sql
SELECT s.ID, s.name, COALESCE(a.i_id, 'NA') AS i_id
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN advisor a
    on s.ID = a.s_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! If possible, could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745364/more-elegant-way-to-perform-join?

Comment: @DeanChong Gordon Linoff is the top SQL person on the site.  He can help you out.