# More elegant way to perform join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image: University database]

Is there more elegant way to join takes, teaches, student and advisor?
I've tried this:

```
select s.ID
from takes natural join
     student as s join
     advisor as a
     on ID = a.s_ID join
     teaches as t
     on takes.course_id = t.course_id and
        takes.sec_id = t.sec_id and
        takes.semester = t.semester and
        takes.year = t.year
where a.i_ID = t.ID)
```

Comment: (1) Do not mix join types (natural join with inner join). (2) I do not see the reason to extract one condition into WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks. (1)I am new to sql and that's what works on my case. Any other ways to do so? I will surely look into it. (2) That is specific to my case too. a.i_ID are not always t.ID

Comment: (1) Use INNER JOIN for all joins. `FROM takes INNER JOIN student as s ON takes.id = s.id INNER JOIN advisor as a ON s.id = a.s_id INNER JOIN ...`.